# Will wait and waitpid block SIGCHLD and unblock it when they return in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, system-calls

Here is my code to examine this:

```
void handler(int n) {
    printf("handler %d\n", n);
    int status;
    if (wait(&status) < 0)
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction sig;
    sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask);
    sig.sa_handler = handler;
    sig.sa_flags = 0;
    sig.sa_restorer = NULL;
    struct sigaction sigold;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sig, &sigold);
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    printf("before fork\n");
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        _exit(127);
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        printf("before waitpid\n");
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
            printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        printf("after waitpid\n");
    }
    printf("after fork\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> before fork
>
> before waitpid
>
> handler 17
>
> No child processes
>
> after waitpid
>
> after fork

So, I think waitpid will block SIGCHLD and wait for child to terminate, once the child terminates, it will do something and the unblock the SIGCHLD before it returns, that's why we see **"No child processes"** error and **"after waitpid"** is after **"handler 17"**, am I right? if not, what is the truth? How to explain the output sequence? Is there a specification for Linux or something like that to check?

Comment: Note [how to avoid calling `printf()` in a signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/).

Comment: That's right, printf is not a reentrant function!

Answer (score 3):

The exit information for a process can only be collected once.  Your output shows the signal handler being called while your code is in `waitpid()`, but the handler calls `wait()` and that collects the information of the child (which you throw away without reporting).  Then when you get back to `waitpid()`, the child exit status has been collected, so there's nothing left for `waitpid()` to report on, hence the `no child processes' error.

Here's an adaptation of your program.  It abuses things by using `printf()` inside the signal handler function, but it seems to work despite that, testing on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (compiling with GCC 7.1.0).

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void handler(int n)
{
    printf("handler %d\n", n);
    int status;
    int corpse;
    if ((corpse = wait(&status)) < 0)
        printf("%s: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
    else
        printf("%s: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", __func__, corpse, status);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sig = { 0 };
    sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask);
    sig.sa_handler = handler;
    sig.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sig, NULL);
    pid_t pid;
    printf("before fork\n");
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        _exit(127);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        printf("before waitpid\n");
        int status;
        int corpse;
        while ((corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) > 0 || errno == EINTR)
        {
            if (corpse < 0)
                printf("loop: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            else
                printf("%s: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", __func__, corpse, status);
        }
        if (corpse < 0)
            printf("%s: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        printf("after waitpid loop\n");
    }
    printf("after fork\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
before fork
before waitpid
handler 20
handler: child 29481 exited with status 0x7F00
loop: Interrupted system call
main: No child processes
after waitpid loop
after fork
```

The status value 0x7F00 is the normal encoding for `_exit(127)`.  The signal number is different for macOS from Linux; that's perfectly permissible.

---

To get the code to compile on Linux (Centos 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS used for the test), using GCC 4.8.5 (almost antediluvian — the current version is GCC 7.1.0) and 5.4.0 respectively, using the command line:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition sg59.c -o sg59
$
```

I added `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 800` before the first header, and used:

```
struct sigaction sig;
memset(&sig, '\0', sizeof(sig));
```

to initialize the structure with GCC 4.8.5.  That sort of shenanigan is occasionally a painful necessity to avoid compiler warnings.  I note that although the `#define` was necessary to expose POSIX symbols, the initializer (`struct sigaction sig = { 0 };`) was accepted by GCC 5.4.0 without problems.

When I then run the program, I get very similar output to what [cong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2659573/cong) reports getting in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949142/will-wait-and-waitpid-block-sigchld-and-unblock-it-when-they-return-in-linux/43949305#comment74940207_43949305):

```
before fork
before waitpid
handler 17
handler: No child processes
main: child 101681 exited with status 0x7F00
main: No child processes
after waitpid loop
after fork
```

It is curious indeed that on Linux, the process is sent a SIGCHLD signal and yet `wait()` cannot wait for it in the signal handler.  That is at least counter-intuitive.

We can debate how much it matters that the first argument to `waitpid()` is `pid` rather than `0`; the error is inevitable on the second iteration of the loop since the first collected the information from the child.  In practice, it doesn't matter here.  In general, it would be better to be using `waitpid(0, &status, WNOHANG)` or thereabouts — depending on context, `0` instead of `WNOHANG` might be better.

Comment: My platform is "gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4", and I run your code in my pc, the output is:
before fork
before waitpid
handler 17
handler: No child processes
main: child 4479 exited with status 0x7F00
main: No child processes
after waitpid loop
after fork

Comment: It is curious that you get a SIGCHLD signal yet calling `wait()` in the handler doesn't reap the child.  It seems odd indeed.  I've reproduced your result on both Centos 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS — noting the code changes necessary to work around antediluvian compilers (GCC 4.x).

Comment: That't why I think waitpid will block SIGCHLD first and unblock it when waitpid is about to return, make sense?

Comment: The only way you could justify that claim is by looking at the source code that implements `waitpid()` — and that might mean the user code or the kernel code or both.  I don't think it's likely.

Comment: Then, is there any other way to know the truth? System call source code is too difficult to read for people in my level.

Comment: Not really, no.